# There is no timeout exception in socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am very confused about sockets... I have two scripts, one is server.py, and second is client.py:

**server.py**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1235))
server.listen(1)

while True:
    client, address = server.accept()

    try:
        client.recv(1024)
    except socket.Timeouterror:
        print 'timeout'
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('ip', 1235))
```

Why server.py script does not show an error of timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the socket calls are blocking, by default. If nothing happens, they would block indefinitely. recv() is one of those calls. Other blocking calls are accept(), recvfrom(), read().

Comment: It doesn't block program, program executes and ends. I want to know why is it happening?

Comment: Thank you for the note. The client.py closes the socket since the process exits after doign the connect. WHen the client.py closes the socket (TCP connection), the recv() call would return on the other side with a return value of 0. So, if you were to do do "x = client.recv(1024)", then the value of x would be 0 and that is why your server program returns too. Your program should check for that. Checking for a return value of 0 is key for TCP receivers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [set the timeout](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket#socket.socket.settimeout) for the socket if you wan to have one:

```
...
client, address = server.accept()
client.settimeout(10)
...
```

Or you can use a [default timeout](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket#socket.setdefaulttimeout) for all sockets.

`socket.Timeouterror` doesn't exist, it should be `socket.timeout`.

Also, you probably should close the client socket, otherwise the client will not know that the connection is closed. The timeout alone doesn't do that for you.

Comment: I have set timeout now, but I get the same results.